# Simulate Python keypresses game

Tags: python

Could someone tell me why this code doesn't work in metin2 and how to fix it, it doesn't respond at all in the game. Wanted to use this so that the game would have the space bar held all the time and key number 4 clicked every 120 seconds, for example.

```
import ctypes
import time

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
_fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
            ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
            ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
_fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
            ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
_fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
            ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
            ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
_fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
             ("mi", MouseInput),
             ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
_fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
            ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
ii_ = Input_I()
ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
ii_ = Input_I()
ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


while (True):
PressKey(0x39)
time.sleep(1)
<code>
```

I tried everything with this code also

```
  from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
  import time
  from threading import Timer

keyboard = Controller()

def hold_space():
keyboard.press(Key.space)
print("Trzymanie spacji...")

def release_space():
keyboard.release(Key.space)
print("Zwolniono spację")

def click_button_4():
keyboard.press('4')
print("Kliknięto przycisk 4")
keyboard.release('4')

def repeat_space_click():
hold_space()
Timer(0.1, release_space).start()  # Zwolnij spację po 1 sekundzie
# Uruchom ponownie klikanie spacją co 1 sekundę
Timer(0.1, repeat_space_click).start()

def repeat_button_4_click():
click_button_4()
# Uruchom ponownie klikanie przycisku 4 co 120 sekund            
Timer(120, repeat_button_4_click).start()

# Uruchom akcje po 5 sekundach
Timer(5, repeat_space_click).start()
Timer(5, repeat_button_4_click).start()

try:
# Uruchom pętlę główną, aby program nie zakończył się natychmiast
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("Przerwano przez użytkownika")
```

so nothing works either, any other ideas?

Comment: It is probably much easier to use [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) or [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), the libraries give much shorter and readable code, and are probably more reliable than `cytpes`. Also, please format your code correctly.

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: MANY games have sophisticated anti-cheat codes to prevent you from doing this kind of thing.  They might be talking directly to the HID devices instead of going through the input queue.

Comment: Trying to target some game to which source isn't available, with no knowledge of what its input mechanism is and what countermeasures it uses to prevent spoofing, is not a reasonable request for this site: we require questions to be narrow and self-contained; such a target is a black box; a nebulous, untestable black-box target makes the question unanswerably broad.

Comment: If I were you, though, I'd buy an embedded development board that can run in USB gadget mode, and use that to emulate a keyboard -- emulate commodity hardware effectively and that takes most countermeasures off the table.

Comment: Does anyone know how to bypass the anti-cheat in metin2 to make it work? I'm asking for educational purposes :)

Comment: Perhaps these programs may be of help. [virtual-keyboard-python](https://github.com/topics/virtual-keyboard-python) It's important to learn the concepts even if you can't use them in the game.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't change anything"? Please elaborate. Did you see any error messages?

Comment: the thing is that these codes work and have no errors, but the game (metin2) does not respond to them at all

Comment: I see. In my experience, [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) has worked really well for me. You can also try [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), but I agree with other comments and their suggestions.